# Multi Step Form using React

Tags: html, css, react.js, jsx, responsive-design

I recently completed the [Multi-Step Form Challenge](https://www.frontendmentor.io/challenges/multistep-form-YVAnSdqQBJ) on Frontend Mentor using React, and I'm eager to receive constructive feedback on my code. I've put in a lot of effort to make the form functional, responsive, and user-friendly, but I believe there's always room for improvement. Your insights and suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm particularly interested in your thoughts on code structure, best practices, and potential optimizations.

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Card1 from './components/Card1';
import Card2 from './components/Card2';
import Card3 from './components/Card3';
import Card4 from './components/Card4';
import Card5 from './components/Card5';

function App() {

  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(1);
  const [details, setDetails] = useState({});
  const [plan, setPlan] = useState("");
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("Monthly");
  const [addOns, setAddOns] = useState([]);

  const handleUserDetails = (name, email, phone) =>{
    setDetails({name, email, phone});
  }

  const capitalizeFirstWord = (str) => !str ? str : str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);

  const handlePlanSelection = (plan) => {
    setPlan(plan);
  }

  const handleModeSelection = (slider) => {
    if (slider === 1) setMode("Monthly");
    else setMode("Yearly");
  }

  const handleAddOnSelection = (addOn) => {
    addOn = capitalizeFirstWord(addOn);
    setAddOns((prev) => {
      if (prev.includes(addOn)) return prev.filter((item) => item !== addOn);
      else return [...prev, addOn];
    });
  };
  
  const handleNextClick = () => {
    setDisplay(display + 1);
  };

  const handleGoBackClick = () => {
    setDisplay(display - 1);
  };

  const handlePlanChange = () => {
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to change plan.")) setDisplay(2);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header step={display}/>
      <Card1 status={display} handleDetails={handleUserDetails} onNextClick={handleNextClick} onGoBackClick={handleGoBackClick}/>
      <Card2 status={display} onNextClick={handleNextClick} onGoBackClick={handleGoBackClick} handlePlan={handlePlanSelection} handleMode={handleModeSelection}/>
      <Card3 status={display} onNextClick={handleNextClick} onGoBackClick={handleGoBackClick} handleAddOns={handleAddOnSelection} selectedAddOns={addOns}/>
      <Card4 status={display} onNextClick={handleNextClick} onGoBackClick={handleGoBackClick} selectedPlan={plan} selectedAddOns={addOns} selectedMode={mode} handlePlanChange={handlePlanChange}/>
      <Card5 status={display} onNextClick={handleNextClick} onGoBackClick={handleGoBackClick} userDetails={details}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**JSX React Components**

**Header.jsx**

```
import React from "react";

function Header(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="headerWrapper">
                <div className="headerBubbles" style={{ backgroundColor: (props.step === 1 || props.step === 5) ? 'hsl(206, 94%, 87%)' : 'transparent', color: (props.step === 1 || props.step === 5) ? 'hsl(213, 96%, 18%)' : 'white' }}>1</div>
                <div className="headerBubbles" style={{ backgroundColor: (props.step === 2 || props.step === 5) ? 'hsl(206, 94%, 87%)' : 'transparent', color: (props.step === 2 || props.step === 5) ? 'hsl(213, 96%, 18%)' : 'white' }}>2</div>
                <div className="headerBubbles" style={{ backgroundColor: (props.step === 3 || props.step === 5) ? 'hsl(206, 94%, 87%)' : 'transparent', color: (props.step === 3 || props.step === 5) ? 'hsl(213, 96%, 18%)' : 'white' }}>3</div>
                <div className="headerBubbles" style={{ backgroundColor: (props.step === 4 || props.step === 5) ? 'hsl(206, 94%, 87%)' : 'transparent', color: (props.step === 4 || props.step === 5) ? 'hsl(213, 96%, 18%)' : 'white' }}>4</div>
            </div>
            <div className="headerWrapperDesktop">
                <div className="headerBubblesDesktop" style={{ backgroundColor: (props.step === 1 || props.step === 5) ? 'hsl(206, 94%, 87%)' : 'transparent', color: (props.step === 1 || props.step === 5) ? 'hsl(213, 96%, 18%)' : 'white' }}>1</div>
                <div className="sideHeaderDetails">
                    <h5 className="headerStep">Step 1</h5>
                    <h5 className="headerStepInfo">YOUR INFO</h5><br></br>
                </div>
                <div className="headerBubblesDesktop" style={{ backgroundColor: (props.step === 2 || props.step === 5) ? 'hsl(206, 94%, 87%)' : 'transparent', color: (props.step === 2 || props.step === 5) ? 'hsl(213, 96%, 18%)' : 'white' }}>2</div>
                <div className="sideHeaderDetails">
                    <h5 className="headerStep">Step 2</h5>
                    <h5 className="headerStepInfo">SELECT PLANS</h5><br></br>
                </div>
                <div className="headerBubblesDesktop" style={{ backgroundColor: (props.step === 3 || props.step === 5) ? 'hsl(206, 94%, 87%)' : 'transparent', color: (props.step === 3 || props.step === 5) ? 'hsl(213, 96%, 18%)' : 'white' }}>3</div>
                <div className="sideHeaderDetails">
                    <h5 className="headerStep">Step 3</h5>
                    <h5 className="headerStepInfo">ADD-ONS</h5><br></br>
                </div>
                <div className="headerBubblesDesktop" style={{ backgroundColor: (props.step === 4 || props.step === 5) ? 'hsl(206, 94%, 87%)' : 'transparent', color: (props.step === 4 || props.step === 5) ? 'hsl(213, 96%, 18%)' : 'white' }}>4</div>
                <div className="sideHeaderDetails">
                    <h5 className="headerStep">Step 4</h5>
                    <h5 className="headerStepInfo">SUMMARY</h5><br></br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

**Card1.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Card1(props) {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
    const [isNameValid, setIsNameValid] = useState(true);
    const [isEmailValid, setIsEmailValid] = useState(true);
    const [isPhoneValid, setIsPhoneValid] = useState(true);

    const handleNameChange = (event) => {
        const newName = event.target.value;
        const namePattern = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
        const isValid = namePattern.test(newName);
        setName(newName);
        setIsNameValid(isValid); 
    };

    const handleEmailChange = (event) => {
        const newEmail = event.target.value;
        const emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
        const isValid = emailPattern.test(newEmail);
        setEmail(newEmail);
        setIsEmailValid(isValid);
    };

    const handlePhoneChange = (event) => {
        const newPhone = event.target.value;
        const phonePattern = /^[0-9]{10}$/;
        const isValid = phonePattern.test(newPhone);
        setPhone(newPhone);
        setIsPhoneValid(isValid); 
    };

    const onNextClick = () => {
        if (isNameValid && isEmailValid && isPhoneValid && name !== "" && email !== "" && phone !== "") {
            props.handleDetails(name, email, phone);
            props.onNextClick();
        }
        else alert("Please fill in all fields correctly.");
    };

    return props.status === 1 ? (
        <div>
            <div className="card1">
                <h1>Personal info</h1>
                <p>Please provide your name, email address, and phone number.</p>
                <label>Name</label><br></br>
                {!isNameValid && (<p className="step1Error">Incorrect Name</p>)}
                <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="e.g. Stephen King" value={name} onChange={handleNameChange}/><br></br>
                <label>Email Address</label><br></br>
                {!isEmailValid && (<p className="step1Error">Incorrect Email Address</p>)}
                <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="e.g. stephenking@lorem.com" value={email} onChange={handleEmailChange}/><br></br>
                <label>Phone Number</label><br></br>
                {!isPhoneValid && (<p className="step1Error">Incorrect Phone Number</p>)}
                <input id="phone" type="text" placeholder="e.g. 9345678900" value={phone} onChange={handlePhoneChange}/>
                <button className="nextBtnDesktop" onClick={onNextClick}>Next Step</button>
            </div>

            <div className="next">
                <button className="nextBtn" onClick={onNextClick}>Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    ) : null;
}

export default Card1;
```

**Card2.jsx**

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

function Card2(props) {
    const [selectedPlan, setSelectedPlan] = useState(null);
    const [slider, setSlider] = useState(1);

    const selectBtn = (plan) => {
        setSelectedPlan(plan);
        props.handleMode(slider);
        props.handlePlan(plan);
    }

    const handleSliderClick = () => {
        if (slider === 1) setSlider(2);
        else setSlider(1);
        setSelectedPlan(null);
    }
    
    const handleNextClick = () => {
        if (selectedPlan === null) alert("Select a plan.");
        else props.onNextClick();
    }

    return props.status === 2 ? (
        <div>
            <div className="card2">
                <h1>Select your plan</h1>
                <p>You have the option of monthly or yearly billing.</p>
                <button className={`step2Btn ${selectedPlan === "Arcade" ? "step2BtnSelected" : "step2Btn"}`} onClick={() => selectBtn("Arcade")}>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40"><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="#FFAF7E" /><path fill="#FFF" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M24.995 18.005h-3.998v5.998h-2v-5.998H15a1 1 0 0 0-1 1V29a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h9.995a1 1 0 0 0 1-1v-9.995a1 1 0 0 0-1-1Zm-5.997 8.996h-2v-1.999h2v2Zm2-11.175a2.999 2.999 0 1 0-2 0v2.18h2v-2.18Z" /></g></svg>
                    <h4>Arcade</h4>
                    <p>{slider === 1 ? "$9/mo" : "$90/yr"}</p>
                    {slider === 2 && (<p id="step2Offer">2 months free</p>)}
                </button>
                <button className={`step2Btn ${selectedPlan === "Advanced" ? "step2BtnSelected" : "step2Btn"}`} onClick={() => selectBtn("Advanced")}>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40"><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="#F9818E" /><path fill="#FFF" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M25.057 15H14.944C12.212 15 10 17.03 10 19.885c0 2.857 2.212 4.936 4.944 4.936h10.113c2.733 0 4.943-2.08 4.943-4.936S27.79 15 25.057 15ZM17.5 20.388c0 .12-.108.237-.234.237h-1.552v1.569c0 .126-.138.217-.259.217H14.5c-.118 0-.213-.086-.213-.203v-1.583h-1.569c-.126 0-.217-.139-.217-.26v-.956c0-.117.086-.213.202-.213h1.584v-1.554c0-.125.082-.231.203-.231h.989c.12 0 .236.108.236.234v1.551h1.555c.125 0 .231.083.231.204v.988Zm5.347.393a.862.862 0 0 1-.869-.855c0-.472.39-.856.869-.856.481 0 .87.384.87.856 0 .471-.389.855-.87.855Zm1.9 1.866a.86.86 0 0 1-.87-.852.86.86 0 0 1 .87-.855c.48 0 .87.38.87.855a.86.86 0 0 1-.87.852Zm0-3.736a.862.862 0 0 1-.87-.854c0-.472.39-.856.87-.856s.87.384.87.856a.862.862 0 0 1-.87.854Zm1.899 1.87a.862.862 0 0 1-.868-.855c0-.472.389-.856.868-.856s.868.384.868.856a.862.862 0 0 1-.868.855Z" /></g></svg>
                    <h4>Advanced</h4>
                    <p>{slider === 1 ? "$12/mo" : "$120/yr"}</p>
                    {slider === 2 && (<p id="step2Offer">2 months free</p>)}
                </button>
                <button className={`step2Btn ${selectedPlan === "Pro" ? "step2BtnSelected" : "step2Btn"}`} onClick={() => selectBtn("Pro")}>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40"><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="#483EFF" /><path fill="#FFF" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M26.666 13H13.334A3.333 3.333 0 0 0 10 16.333v7.193a3.447 3.447 0 0 0 2.14 3.24c1.238.5 2.656.182 3.56-.8L18.52 23h2.96l2.82 2.966a3.2 3.2 0 0 0 3.56.8 3.447 3.447 0 0 0 2.14-3.24v-7.193A3.333 3.333 0 0 0 26.666 13Zm-9.333 6H16v1.333a.667.667 0 0 1-1.333 0V19h-1.333a.667.667 0 0 1 0-1.334h1.333v-1.333a.667.667 0 1 1 1.333 0v1.333h1.333a.667.667 0 1 1 0 1.334Zm7.333 2a2.667 2.667 0 1 1 0-5.333 2.667 2.667 0 0 1 0 5.333ZM26 18.333a1.333 1.333 0 1 1-2.667 0 1.333 1.333 0 0 1 2.667 0Z" /></g></svg>
                    <h4>Pro</h4>
                    <p>{slider === 1 ? "$15/mo" : "$150/yr"}</p>                    
                    {slider === 2 && (<p id="step2Offer">2 months free</p>)}
                </button>
                <div className="sliderParent">
                    <h4 className="sliderLabel">Monthly</h4>
                    <div class="slider">
                        <div id="sliderHandle" onClick={handleSliderClick} style={{ left: slider === 1 ? "0%" : "76%" }}></div>
                    </div>
                    <h4 className="sliderLabel">Yearly</h4>
                </div>

                <button className="goBackBtnDesktop" onClick={props.onGoBackClick}>Go Back</button>
                <button className="nextBtnDesktop" onClick={handleNextClick}>Next Step</button>

            </div>

            <div className="next">
                <button className="goBackBtn" onClick={props.onGoBackClick}>Go Back</button>
                <button className="nextBtn" onClick={handleNextClick}>Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    ) : null;
}

export default Card2;
```

**Card3.jsx**

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";

function Card3(props) {
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const selectedAddOns = props.selectedAddOns;
        for (const addon of selectedAddOns) {
          let id;
          if (addon === "Online service") id = "check1";
          else if (addon === "Larger storage") id = "check2";
          else if (addon === "Customizable profile") id = "check3";
          const div = document.getElementById(id);
          if (div) div.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(173, 190, 255)';
        }
    });
      
    const handleCheckMarkClick = (event) => {
        const div = event.currentTarget; 
        const id = div.id;
        let currentBackgroundColor = div.style.backgroundColor;
        if (currentBackgroundColor === 'rgb(173, 190, 255)') div.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        else div.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(173, 190, 255)';
        if (id === 'check1') props.handleAddOns('Online service');
        else if (id === 'check2') props.handleAddOns('Larger storage');
        else props.handleAddOns('Customizable profile');
    }

    return props.status === 3 ? (
        <div>
            <div className="card3">
                <h1>Pick add-ons</h1>
                <p>Add-ons help enhance your gaming experience.</p>
                <button className="step3Btn" >
                    <div className="step3BtnCheck" id="check1" onClick={handleCheckMarkClick}><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12" height="9" viewBox="0 0 12 9"><path fill="none" stroke="#FFF" stroke-width="2" d="m1 4 3.433 3.433L10.866 1" /></svg></div>
                    <div className="step3BtnDetails">
                        <h2 className="step3BtnHeading">Online service</h2>
                        <h4 className="step3BtnSubHeading">Access to multiplayer games</h4>
                        <p className="step3BtnPrice">+$1/mo</p>
                    </div>
                </button>
                <button className="step3Btn" >
                    <div className="step3BtnCheck" id="check2" onClick={handleCheckMarkClick}><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12" height="9" viewBox="0 0 12 9"><path fill="none" stroke="#FFF" stroke-width="2" d="m1 4 3.433 3.433L10.866 1" /></svg></div>
                    <div className="step3BtnDetails" id="step3BtnSecond">
                        <h2 className="step3BtnHeading">Larger storage</h2>
                        <h4 className="step3BtnSubHeading">Extra 1TB of cloud save</h4>
                        <p className="step3BtnPrice">+$2/mo</p>
                    </div>
                </button>
                <button className="step3Btn" >
                    <div className="step3BtnCheck" id="check3" onClick={handleCheckMarkClick}><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12" height="9" viewBox="0 0 12 9"><path fill="none" stroke="#FFF" stroke-width="2" d="m1 4 3.433 3.433L10.866 1" /></svg></div>
                    <div className="step3BtnDetails">
                        <h2 className="step3BtnHeading">Customizable Profile</h2>
                        <h4 className="step3BtnSubHeading">Custom theme on your profile</h4>
                        <p className="step3BtnPrice">+$2/mo</p>
                    </div>
                </button>
                <button className="goBackBtnDesktop" onClick={props.onGoBackClick}>Go Back</button>
                <button className="nextBtnDesktop" onClick={props.onNextClick}>Next Step</button>
            </div>
            
            <div className="next">
                <button className="goBackBtn" onClick={props.onGoBackClick}>Go Back</button>
                <button className="nextBtn" onClick={props.onNextClick}>Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    ) : null;
}

export default Card3;
```

**Card4.jsx**

```
import React from "react";

function Card4(props) {
    let addOns = props.selectedAddOns;
    let addOnPrices = ["$1/mo", "$2/mo", "$2/mo"];
    let planValue = "";

    const extractNumberFromString = (inputString) => {
        const regex = /\d+/;
        const match = inputString.match(regex);
        if (match) return parseInt(match[0], 10);
        else return null;
    }

    const handlePlan = (plan, mode) =>{
        if (plan === 'Arcade' && mode === "Monthly") planValue = '$9/mo';
        else if (plan === 'Advanced' && mode === "Monthly") planValue = '$12/mo';
        else if (plan === 'Pro' && mode === "Monthly") planValue = '$15/mo';
        else if (plan === 'Arcade' && mode === "Yearly") planValue = '$90/yr';
        else if (plan === 'Advanced' && mode === "Yearly") planValue = '$120/yr';
        else if (plan === 'Pro' && mode === "Yearly") planValue = '$150/yr';
        return planValue;
    }

    const calculateTotal = () => {
        let total = 0, res = "";
        if (props.selectedMode === "Monthly") {
            total = extractNumberFromString(planValue);
            for (let addOn of addOns) {
                if (addOn === "Online service") total += 1;
                if (addOn === "Larger storage") total += 2;
                if (addOn === "Customizable profile") total += 2;
            }
            res = "+$" + total + "/mo";
        }
        else {
            total = extractNumberFromString(planValue);
            for (let addOn of addOns) {
                if (addOn === "Online service") total += 10;
                if (addOn === "Larger storage") total += 20;
                if (addOn === "Customizable profile") total += 20;
            }
            res = "+$" + total + "/yr";
        }
        return res;
    }

    return props.status === 4 ? (
        <div>
            <div className="card4">
                <h1>Finishing up</h1>
                <p>Double-check everything looks OK before confirming.</p>
                <div className="planSummaryBox">
                    <h4 className="step4PlanName">{props.selectedPlan} ({props.selectedMode})</h4>
                    <h4 id="planValue">{handlePlan(props.selectedPlan, props.selectedMode)}</h4><br></br>
                    <button id="changePlanBtn" onClick={props.handlePlanChange}>Change</button>
                    <hr />
                    {addOns.map((addOn, index) => (
                        <div key={index}>
                            <h5>{addOn}</h5>
                            <h5 className="step4AddOnValue">{addOn === "Online service" ? addOnPrices[0] : addOn === "Larger storage" ? addOnPrices[1] : addOnPrices[2]}</h5>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
                <h5 className="step4Total">Total (per {props.selectedMode === "Monthly" ? 'month' : 'year'})</h5>
                <h4 className="step4TotalValue">{calculateTotal()}</h4><br></br>
                <button className="goBackBtnDesktop" onClick={props.onGoBackClick} style={{marginTop: "5%"}}>Go Back</button>
                <button className="nextBtnDesktop" onClick={props.onNextClick} style={{marginTop: "5%"}}>Confirm</button>
            </div>

            <div className="next">
                <button className="goBackBtn" onClick={props.onGoBackClick}>Go Back</button>
                <button className="nextBtn" onClick={props.onNextClick}>Confirm</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    ) : null;
}

export default Card4;
```

**Card5.jsx**

```
import React from "react";

function Card5(props){
    return props.status === 5 ? (
        <div className="card5">
            <div className="thankYouBox">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 80 80"><g fill="none"><circle cx="40" cy="40" r="40" fill="#F9818E"/><path fill="#E96170" d="M48.464 79.167c.768-.15 1.53-.321 2.288-.515a40.04 40.04 0 0 0 3.794-1.266 40.043 40.043 0 0 0 3.657-1.63 40.046 40.046 0 0 0 12.463-9.898A40.063 40.063 0 0 0 78.3 51.89c.338-1.117.627-2.249.867-3.391L55.374 24.698a21.6 21.6 0 0 0-15.332-6.365 21.629 21.629 0 0 0-15.344 6.365c-8.486 8.489-8.486 22.205 0 30.694l23.766 23.775Z"/><path fill="#FFF" d="M40.003 18.333a21.58 21.58 0 0 1 15.31 6.351c8.471 8.471 8.471 22.158 0 30.63-8.47 8.47-22.156 8.47-30.627 0-8.47-8.472-8.47-22.159 0-30.63a21.594 21.594 0 0 1 15.317-6.35Zm9.865 15c-.316.028-.622.15-.872.344l-12.168 9.13-5.641-5.642c-1.224-1.275-3.63 1.132-2.356 2.356l6.663 6.663c.56.56 1.539.63 2.173.156l13.326-9.995c1.122-.816.43-2.993-.956-3.013a1.666 1.666 0 0 0-.17 0Z"/></g></svg>
                <h1>Thank you!</h1>
                <p>Thanks for confirming your subscription! We hope you have fun using our platform. If you ever need support, please feel free to email us at support@loremgaming.com.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    ) : null;
}

export default Card5;
```

**App.css**

```
body {
  background-image: url(../assets/images/bg-sidebar-mobile.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto; 
  background-position: top center; 
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-color: hsl(205, 46%, 92%);
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

h1{
  color: hsl(213, 96%, 18%);
}

h4{
  color: hsl(213, 96%, 18%);
  margin: 0%;
}

h5{
  margin: 2%;
  color: gray;
  font-weight: lighter;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

hr{
  border: solid gray 1px;
  margin: 5%;
}

label{
  color: hsl(213, 96%, 18%);
  font-weight: bold;
}

p{
  color: grey;
}

input{
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 2%;
  width: 70%;
}

.headerWrapper{
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 5% 10% 0% 10%;
}

.headerWrapperDesktop{
  display: none;
}

.headerBubbles{
  display: inline-flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center; 
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: white solid 1.5px;
  color: white;
  margin: 2% 5% 0% 5%;
  padding: 4%;
  width: 1rem; 
  height: 1rem;
}

.card1, .card2, .card3, .card4, .card5{
  width: 70%;
  border-radius: 5%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 15% 10% 0% 10%;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding: 5%;
}

.card3{
  margin: 5% 10% 0% 10%;
}

.card5{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10%;
  margin: 10% 5% 0% 5%;
}

.step1Error{
  color: red;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 0%;
}

.step2Btn{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

#step2Offer{
  margin-left: 15%;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: hsl(213, 96%, 18%);
  text-align: center
}

.step2Btn svg{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0%;
}

.step2Btn h4, .step2Btn p{
  margin: 3%;
}

.step2Btn:hover{
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.step2BtnSelected{
  border-color: hsl(213, 96%, 18%);
  background-color: hsl(228, 100%, 84%);
}

.sliderParent {
  background-color: hsl(227, 85%, 92%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.sliderLabel {
  color: hsl(213, 96%, 18%);
  font-weight: bolder;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider {
  flex: 0.3;
  position: relative;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: hsl(213, 96%, 18%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

#sliderHandle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: left 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.step3Btn{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 3%;
  margin: 5% 0% 5% 0%;
  border: gray solid 0.1px;
  border-radius: 3%;
}

.step3BtnDetails{
  float: right;
}

.step3BtnCheck{
  display: inline-flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center; 
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: gray solid 0.1px;
}

.step3BtnHeading{
  float: left;
  margin: 2%;
  display: inline-flex;
  color: hsl(213, 96%, 18%);
}

.step3BtnSubHeading{
  float: left;
  margin: 2%;
  display: inline-flex;
  color: gray;
}

.step3BtnPrice{
  float: right;
  color: hsl(228, 100%, 84%);
}

.planSummaryBox{
  background-color: hsl(208, 65%, 95%);
  color: hsl(213, 96%, 18%);
  padding: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

#changePlanBtn{
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: underline;
  border: none;
  background-color: hsl(206, 94%, 87%);
  margin: 0%;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.step4PlanName{
  display: inline-flex;
  float: left;
}

#planValue{
  display: inline-flex;
  float: right;
}

.step4AddOnValue{
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  color: hsl(213, 96%, 18%);
}

.step4Total{
  margin: 5%;
  color: gray;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline;
}

.step4TotalValue{
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 25%;
  color: hsl(243, 100%, 62%);
}

.next{
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  width: 90%;
  bottom: 0%;
  padding: 5%;
}

.goBackBtn{
  margin-top: 4%;
  color: gray;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
}

.nextBtn{
  background-color: hsl(213, 96%, 18%);
  color: white;
  padding: 2%;
  width: 25%;
  font-size: large;
  float: right;
}

.nextBtnDesktop, .goBackBtnDesktop{
  display: none;
}

/* Desktop CSS */

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  body{
    background: none;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .headerWrapperDesktop{
    display: block;
    background-image: url(../assets/images/bg-sidebar-desktop.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 87vh;
    float: left;
    padding: 2%;
    border-radius: 3%;
    width: 15%;
    margin: 1% 0% 0% 1%;
  }
  .headerWrapper{
    display: none;
  }
  .headerBubblesDesktop{
    display: inline-flex; 
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center; 
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: white solid 1.5px;
    color: white;
    margin: 2% 5% 0% 5%;
    padding: 4%;
    width: 1rem; 
    height: 1rem;
  }
  .sideHeaderDetails {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0% 0% 2% 2%;
  }
  .headerStep{
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    margin: 0%;
    font-weight: lighter;
  }
  .headerStepInfo{
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    margin: 0%;
    margin-top: 2%;
  }
  .card1, .card2, .card3, .card4, .card5{
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 0%;
    margin: 0% 0% 0% 30%;
    padding: 2%;
  }
  input{
    width: 100%;
    height: 2rem;
  }
  .step2Btn{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 3% 5% 5% 3%;
    padding: 3%;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .step2Btn svg{
    float: left;
    margin: 2% 0% 2% 0%;
  }
  #step2Offer{
    margin-left: 30%;
  }
  .sliderParent{
    margin: 2% 0% 5% 0%;
  }
  .step3Btn{
    width: 80%;
    padding: 2%;
    margin: 0% 0% 2% 0%;
    border: gray solid 0.1px;
    border-radius: 2%;
    height: fit-content;
  }
  .step3BtnDetails{
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    float: left;
    margin: 0% 10% 0% 25%;
  }
  #step3BtnSecond{
    margin-left: 30%;
  }
  .step3BtnHeading{
    margin: 0% 0% 0% 5%;
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center; 
  }
  .step3BtnSubHeading{
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: 1%;
  }
  .step3BtnPrice{
    margin: 0%;
  }  
  .planSummaryBox{
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    padding: 3%;
  }
  .step4Total{
    margin: 5%;
    display: inline;
  }
  .step4TotalValue{
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 60%;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
  .thankYouBox{
    margin-top: 20%;
  }
  .next{
    display: none;
  }
  .nextBtnDesktop{
    display: block;
    border-radius: 4%;
    background-color: hsl(257, 89%, 59%);
    color: white;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 25%;
    font-size: medium;
    float: right;
  }
  .goBackBtnDesktop{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 2%;
    color: gray;
    border: none;
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

Live Site URL - [Click Here](https://chayansurana3.github.io/P10-Multi-Step-Form/)

Source Repo - [Click Here](https://github.com/chayansurana3/P10-Multi-Step-Form.git)

Comment: I didn't add the tag [tag:programming-challenge] though it could be added if desired over one of the existing tags. Per its guidance: "_Use this tag when the code is a solution to a programming challenge. **Always include a sufficient description of the problem to be solved - while a link to the challenge is welcome, the review request needs to be complete when the challenge site is unavailable**._" (emphasis mine)

Comment: One thing that can improve the UX, is to make the "Pick add-ons" boxes clickable instead of just relying on the small checkboxes.